# Unchecked call to super of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have implemented a custom Array Adapter and though the app works fine, but I get this error when on super line:

**Unchecked call to ArrayAdapter(Context, int, T[]) as a member of raw type Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter**

This is my custom ArrayAdapter:

```
class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Object[] objects)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

**super** is highlighted as error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The exact issue which I faced. Please consider clearing my doubt which I asked in the comment section in the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your class declaration to:

```
class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object>
```

By the way consider using something more specific than `Object` - it will be more convenient for you too.

Comment: Changed it to string, Thanks.

Comment: By changing it to Object, my warning is fixed. I looked at getItem() method which has a "Object" as return type. My doubt is, whether we receive the expected output from the getItem() method if we extend ArrayAdapter class.
Sorry it is a lame question. I am very new to this one.

Comment: @Pravin I did not entirely get your question.

Comment: I have two ArrayAdapter templates (Two class files which extends ArrayAdapter). For a file when I changed ArrayAdapter<Object>, it did not showed any warning. But for another file when I changed to ArrayAdapter<Object> it is showing "Unchecked assignment: 
'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.List<java.lang.Object>'"

1) public NTrackAttendanceAdapter(Context context, String[] studentNames, ArrayList<String> attendanceRowArrayList) My first ArrayAdapter Template
My second class file is in next comment

Comment: 2) public NTrackDriverTripsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList studentNames, ArrayList passengersArrayList, ArrayList vehicleRegNumberArrayList, ArrayList tripTimingArrayList)

Comment: @Pravin if you use Array adapter of strings why don't you declare it `ArrayAdapter<String>`?

Comment: By giving <String> in the NTrackAttendanceAdapter, an error message is shown as "getItem(int)" in NTrackAttendanceAdapter clashes with getItem(int) in android.widget.ArrayAdapter ; Attempting to use in incompattible return type. (This first doubt which I raised).

Comment: Waht do you return from `getItem`? String or object?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [ArrayAdapter class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), it's a generic `class`. So you have to specify which type of datas will be manipulate through your adapter.  For example, if you manipulate Strings :

```
class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
//
}
```

Comment: Sir ! what do you call those inside <> ? is it kind of input/output type? I'm new to this.